# Listing every street name per postal code

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, germany

I would like to export a list of all street names per postal code for Germany. 
More specificly, I have looked at OpenStreetMap/the Overpass API.

With

```
[out:json];
(
    area[postal_code="31061"];
);
way(area)[highway][name];
out;
```

i can get a list containing information about every street in the postal code "31061 - Alfeld".

Now, I could just use a public API, but I don't think they'd be happy with me firing 30k requests against their API.

I could host my own version of the Overpass API, altough that requires very large amounts of resources (HDD and RAM). I tried importing the dataset for germany, but had limited success due to the large file sizes.

There has to be a better solution to get the data I would like to have.

Is there maybe a commandline-tool available, that can extract all streets for a specific postal code from a http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html dump?

Comment: 30k will be too much for one day (limit is 10k), but you could spread this across several days/week. Also, what exactly do you mean by "very large amounts of resources"? What did you try? Did you enable compression?

Comment: @mmd I keep running against "Dispatcher_Client::request_read_and_idx::timeout" errors, altough having 16GiB RAM in the machine and tweaking the settings... (with overpass)

Comment: Can you post the query in question as overpass turbo share link?

Comment: @mmd http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/oUL - overpass turbo seems to have no problems with the query, it instantly finishes.

Comment: I think GIS SE is probably not a good place to discuss issues with your local Overpass instance. However, there's a dev mailing list you might want to refer to: https://listes.openstreetmap.fr/wws/info/overpass

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a command line tool available. You can probably build something similar with [osmium-tool](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/). However it will take ages to process a raw PBF or XML file until obtaining all the information you are interested in. You will have to re-read the file for each query and you can't really perform spatial queries against it.